# SLDS Ligntning Design Tokens

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have created one design tokens with the name like "myDefaultBorderBottom" under defaultTokens. Later I realized I am not going to use that. How to delete or modify that tokens in default tokens. suggestions please.

Because when I delete or modify I am unable to save the css file. Getting a error like this...

Failed to save Component2.css: The token 'myDefaultBorderBottom' was not found on the TOKENS markup://c:defaultTokens

Answer (score 2):

In the Developer Console, select **File | New | Lightning Tokens.**
Name it defaultTokens and click Submit.
Add **extends="forceCommunity:base"** to the code. The complete code looks like this.

```
<aura:tokens extends="forceCommunity:base">
</aura:tokens>
```